# stopping rotating images when popup dialog box is active

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript functions to rotate images in an orbital manner. I also have created a popup dialog box as well. What I am trying to do is have it so that when the dialog box is active, the images stop even if i were to mouseout from the image.

Here is my javascript functions I have made:

```
var popupStatus = 0;
var timer = null;
var m = {
Z   : 100,
xm  : 0,
xmm : .25,
ymm : 0,
ym  : 0,
mx  : 0,
nx  : 0,
ny  : 0,
nw  : 0,
nh  : 0,
xR  : 0,
nI  : 0,
scr : 0,
img : 0,


run : function () {
    m.xm += (m.xmm - m.xm) * .1;
    if (m.ym < m.nw * .15) m.ym++;
    m.xR += m.xm;
    for (var i = 0; i < m.nI; i++){
        var A = (i * 360 / m.nI) + m.xR;
        var x = Math.cos(A * (Math.PI / 180));
        var y = Math.sin(A * (Math.PI / 180));
        var a = m.img[i];
        a.style.width  = ''.concat(Math.round(Math.abs(y * m.ym) + y * m.Z), 'px');
        a.style.left   = ''.concat(Math.round((m.nw * .5) + x * ((m.nw * .5) - (m.nw * .05)) - ((Math.abs(y * m.ym) + y * m.Z) * .5)), 'px');
        a.style.height = ''.concat(Math.round(m.ym + y * m.Z), 'px');
        a.style.top    = ''.concat(Math.round((m.nh * .5) - (m.ym * .5) - x * (m.Z * .5) - (m.ymm * y)), 'px');
        a.style.zIndex = 600 + Math.round(y);
        m.setOpacity(a, (y * 50) + 100);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(m.run, 30);
},

resize : function () {
    m.nx  = m.scr.offsetLeft;
    m.ny  = m.scr.offsetTop;
    m.nw  = m.scr.offsetWidth;
    m.nh  = m.scr.offsetHeight;
},

mousemove : function (e) {
    if (window.event) e = window.event;
    m.xmm = (m.nx + (m.nw * .5) - (e.x || e.clientX)) / (m.nw * .25);
    m.ymm = (m.ny + (m.nh * .5) - (e.y || e.clientY)) / (m.nh * .005);
},

setOpacity : function (obj, a) {
    if (a < 0) a = 0; else if (a > 100) a = 100;
    if (obj.filters) obj.filters.alpha.opacity = a;
    else obj.style.opacity = a / 100;
},

init : function () {
    m.scr = document.getElementById("screen");
    m.img = m.scr.getElementsByTagName("img");
    m.nI  = m.img.length;
    window.onresize = m.resize;

    m.resize();
    m.ym = m.Z;
    m.run();
}


}
function stop(){
clearTimeout(timer);
}


onload = function() {
m.init();
}





function loadPopup(){
//loads popup only if it is disabled
if(popupStatus==0){
    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "opacity": "0.7"
    });
    $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
    popupStatus = 1;
}
();
}


function disablePopup(){
//disables popup only if it is enabled
if(popupStatus==1){
    $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
    popupStatus = 0;
}
}

//centering popup
function posPopup(){
//request data for centering
var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();
//centering
$("#popupContact").css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/350,
    "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/8
});
//only need force for IE6

$("#backgroundPopup").css({
    "height": windowHeight
});

}


//CONTROLLING EVENTS IN jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){

//LOADING POPUP
//Click the button event!
$("#button").click(function(){
    //centering with css
    posPopup();
    //load popup
    loadPopup();
    stop();

});
});
```

Comment: Can you include a JSfiddle? You will receive a much better response to your question

Comment: We're going to need to know some information about the implementation before we can help. Are you rotating the images using JS, CSS transitions, flash or something else? What sort of popup is it - a separate browser window or some sort of JavaScript powered one?